# How to measure/convert CSS text margin/padding in the Photoshop?

Tags: css, text, margin, photoshop, psd

*How to get CSS text margin/padding from the Photoshop?*

*or*

*How to convert the distance from/to the text in Photoshop into CSS margin/padding?*

Distances from text elements (paragraphs) in Photoshop do not correspond to margins/paddings in the CSS. Distances are measured, for example, using smart guides:

[image: PS screenshot 0]

All because the line height is not used in the distances calculation. Therefore, the first recommendation I found is to use the **formula**:

```
margin_in_CSS = distance_in_PS - (line-height - font-size) / 2
```

or shorter:

```
CSS = PS - (line-height - font-size) / 2
```

This is the distance from some obvious border (line) to the text element. For the distance between two paragraphs we use, respectively:

```
CSS = PS - (line-height_1 - font-size_1) / 2 - (line-height_2 - font-size_2) / 2
```

As the font size increases, it becomes clear that this formula is not enough. The **actual height** of the line (obtained with the selection tool) in Photoshop is even ***less*** than the font size!

[image: PS screenshot 1]

Although the photoshop still considers the height of the element to be approximately equal to the font size, which does not affect the distance to it :(. For example, on the Properties tab:

[image: PS screenshot 2]

I calculated that the **difference** between the real height of the line and the font size is about **30%** or **15%** at the top and bottom of the text (I'm not saying this is 100% true!). And now I use the **formula**:

```
CSS = PS - (0.15 * font-size + (line-height - font-size) / 2)
```

Or between two paragraphs:

```
CSS = PS - (0.15 * font-size_1 + (line-height_1 - font-size_1) / 2)
         - (0.15 * font-size_2 + (line-height_2 - font-size_2) / 2)
```

Similarly, we can not rely on the correct definition of the height of a paragraph in several lines by Photoshop. But here the situation is simpler, the real height of the paragraph in the CSS will be:

```
height = line-height * num_of_lines
```

The **question** is, *is there a simpler way?* О_о

Sorry for my English ^_^

---

*UPDATE*, shorter formulas:

*text <> border*

```
CSS = PS - (line-height - 0.7 * font-size) / 2
```

*text <> text*

```
CSS = PS - (line-height_1 - 0.7 * font-size_1) / 2
         - (line-height_2 - 0.7 * font-size_2) / 2
```

---

*UPDATE*:

Now a script is being developed for the correct calculation of distances on the Adobe forum ([link](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2429690)). At the moment, the script can calculate the distance from the bounding box of the text line with a standard (auto) line-height of 120%.

---

*UPDATE*:

It does not matter if you use a pointed text or a paragraph text, the result bounding box height is not equal to the text line-height (leading)

[image: bounding box height]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the script for measuring vertical distance is finished!
It can correctly calculate the vertical distance for CSS between layers, one of which or both are text layers.

Here's the link on Adobe Forums - [A script for measuring the distance between two elements?](https://forums.adobe.com/message/10061259#10061259)

```
// version no CS6 or no effects

var old_units = app.preferences.rulerUnits;    
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;    

try { app.activeDocument.suspendHistory("Get Text Bounds", "var bounds = get_selected_layers_bounds()") } catch(e) { alert(e); }  

try { executeAction( charIDToTypeID( "undo" ), undefined, DialogModes.NO ); } catch(e) { alert(e); }  

app.preferences.rulerUnits = old_units;    

if (bounds)    
    {    
    if (bounds.length == 2)    
        {    
        var distance = 0;

        if (bounds[0].bottom <= bounds[1].top) distance = bounds[1].top - bounds[0].bottom;    
        else if (bounds[1].bottom <= bounds[0].top) distance = bounds[0].top - bounds[1].bottom;    

        else  alert("Intersecting layers")    

        var distance_in_css = distance - (bounds[0].leading - 1.2*bounds[0].size)/2 - (bounds[1].leading - 1.2*bounds[1].size)/2;

        alert("distance = " + distance + "\ndistance_in_css = " + distance_in_css);
        }    
    else    
        alert("More then 2 selected layers")     

    }    
else     
    alert("There is no selected layers")     

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
function get_selected_layers_bounds()    
    {    
    try {    
        var ref = new ActionReference();    

        ref.putProperty( charIDToTypeID( "Prpr" ), stringIDToTypeID( "targetLayers" ) );    
        ref.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID("Dcmn"), charIDToTypeID("Ordn"), charIDToTypeID("Trgt") );    
        var desc = executeActionGet(ref);    

        if (!desc.hasKey( stringIDToTypeID("targetLayers") ) ) return null;    

        var n = 0;    
        try { activeDocument.backgroundLayer } catch (e) { n = 1; }    

        desc = desc.getList( stringIDToTypeID("targetLayers"));    

        var len = desc.count;    

        var selected_bounds = new Array();    

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)    
            {    
            try     
                {    
                var r = new ActionReference();    
                r.putIndex( charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " ), desc.getReference(i).getIndex() + n);    

                var ret = executeActionGet(r);    

                var size    = 0;
                var leading = 0;

                if (ret.hasKey(stringIDToTypeID("textKey")))  
                    {  
                    var textStyleRangeList = ret.getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID("textKey")).getList(charIDToTypeID("Txtt" ));

                    if (textStyleRangeList.count > 1) { alert("More than one textStyleRange in layer", "Oops!!"); }

                    var textStyle = textStyleRangeList.getObjectValue(0).getObjectValue(charIDToTypeID("TxtS" ));

                    var auto_leading = textStyle.getBoolean(stringIDToTypeID("autoLeading"));

                    size = textStyle.getUnitDoubleValue(stringIDToTypeID("size"));
                    leading = auto_leading?size*1.2:textStyle.getUnitDoubleValue(stringIDToTypeID("leading"));

                    var s = ret.getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID("textKey")).getString(charIDToTypeID("Txt " ));  
                    s = s.replace(/^./gm, String.fromCharCode(0x2588));  

                    var d1 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                    d1.putReference( charIDToTypeID( "null" ), r );  

                    var d2 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                    d2.putString( charIDToTypeID( "Txt " ), s);  

                    d1.putObject( charIDToTypeID( "T   " ), charIDToTypeID( "TxLr" ), d2 );  

                    executeAction( charIDToTypeID( "setd" ), d1, DialogModes.NO );  

                    ret = executeActionGet(r);    
                    }  


                // var bounds = ret.getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID("bounds"));  // use this in CS6 or when you want to take into account the effects    

                var bounds = ret.getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID("boundsNoEffects")); // in CS6 does not work    

                var obj = { 
                          left   : bounds.getUnitDoubleValue(stringIDToTypeID("left")),    
                          top    : bounds.getUnitDoubleValue(stringIDToTypeID("top")),    
                          right  : bounds.getUnitDoubleValue(stringIDToTypeID("right")),    
                          bottom : bounds.getUnitDoubleValue(stringIDToTypeID("bottom")),
                          size   : size,
                          leading: leading,
                          };    

                    selected_bounds.push(obj);    
                }

                catch (e) { alert(e); return null; }    
            }    

            return selected_bounds;    
        }    

    catch (e) { alert(e); return null; }    
}
```

The script should be saved as a *.js or *.jsx file (for example, *distance.js*) in the Photoshop folder - *C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC 2017\Presets\Scripts*

It will be available in the Photoshop menu - File > Scripts > Distance

Answer (score 8):

> *How to convert the distance from/to the text in Photoshop into CSS margin/padding?*

The actual resulting glyph(s) (pink border in your image) of your text will have different height with the following contents:

- "
- [*empty space*] = no glyph at all
- ...
- a
- A
- Qq
- q

Margins and paddings ***should not be measured from*** the text itself, but from the boundaries of text line (or `line-height` in CSS).

In the above example:

[image]

`65px` is the actual height of text line (or `line-height` in CSS), (the distance from two text baselines when the text wraps) and what is used when calculating margin/padding. The end result being that no matter the contents of your text element, the distance from its baseline to the element following it should remain the same, based on `line-height`, (bottom) `margin` and (bottom) `padding` (and, of course, on the top margin and padding of next element).

To answer your question in a nutshell, **PS does not apply a reduction to margins.** It's just they are not calculated from the bounding box of the text glyphs (which might vary depending on contents), but from the bounding box of text line.

Another thing to consider when converting from `.psd` to HTML is that in HTML you have [collapsing margins](https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/). In short, from two vertical adjacent margins only the largest one will be kept. If the other one is negative, it will be deducted from the positive one and if both are negative, the one with the largest value will be applied.

Comment: The distances in PS are calculated from _the bounding box of **characters**_,  at least with the smart guides - check the first screenshot again. That is the problem. And in CSS, the distances are calculated from the _bounding box of the **text line**_... So the question is how to measure it from the _bounding box of the text line in PS_???

Comment: I believe you are wrong. The distance in PS is also calculated from line-box. To get the line-box in PS you can convert your text to paragraph text and it's box will be defaulted to the text-line. If what you say would be true, the line-height would vary based on contents, but it doesn't.

Comment: No, I think I'm right. Pls check my last update with screenshot. It does not matter if you use a pointed text or a paragraph text, the result bounding box height is not equal to the text line height (line-height = leading)

Answer (score 0):

it does not matter , psd is for showing how the website looks on completion you have to take in consideration the font size , for e.g. for paragraph text if the font size is 14 pt in psd and the grid is 1200px (bootstrap) than you have to convert the font in aspect ratio of browser ( default 16px now in bootstrap ) and calculate accordingly like 14pt in psd is equals to 14px + (14 * 0.16%)px in browser and everything else accordingly , similar for line height.
also if you want to set font size same as psd its up to you select 14px for html if our psd font size is 14pt for paragraph.